# What is the requirement to become Windows Phone developer?

Tags: apps, windows-mobile, developer-preview

Recently I'm learning basic open source programming language like PHP, Java, html etc. base on recently on demand for Microsoft platform and I have no idea where to start with Windows Phone apps development.

Where to start learning from scratch to become Windows Phone developer? what programing language I need to get start?

Comment: Have you seen https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend starting on Windows Phone, since that's dead. Instead go for Windows 10 UWP apps. You will need Windows 10 to do this. Here are some points I'd start with.

**Get a developer account**

Instructions can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868184.aspx).

**Get your PC ready for development**

Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developers and turn on Developer Mode.

[**Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146)

This is the IDE you'll probably want to use.

**C# and XAML**

These are the languages I'd use. You can find a tutorial [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn765018.aspx). There are also tons of samples [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). If you're willing to spend quite a bit of money, the [C# Learning Path](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/learning-path/c-sharp.do) by Eric Lippert ought to give you a very good understanding of the language.

You should also read Microsoft's [guidelines](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/windows-apps).

Answer (score 1):

The most important requirement: to develop for Windows Phone 8, you must have computer with Windows Phone 8. To use Windows Phone 8 emulator you must have Windows 8 Professional on your computer. Also you can test apps on Windows Phone device, but you should unlock device at first.
To publich apps on Windows Store you should buy an account, but it is free for students.

You can develop native apps using C# and XAML. Also it is possible to develop apps using HTML.